# c++ boost::asio p2p networking

Tags: c++, networking, boost, boost-asio, p2p

I want to create a p2p network using boost::asio tcp protocol.
I give the first listening port in which the p2p node starts listening, and if I give a port that I want to connect to, I want the listening port to connect to the given port.
(all the sockets performed on the localhost IP)

for example:

```
listening port - 10 (accepting clients)
connect to port: 20
creates a new socket: 10 -> 20
```

where I try to use the function do_connect it gives me the error:

> "Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:10: An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket"

I guess the problem is with the socket I getting from the acceptor.get_executor().
How can I get the listening port and connect it to the other endpoint?

the main:

```
try
    {
        boost::asio::io_context io_context;
        int port;
        int option;
        std::cout << "enter the port you are listening in: " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> port;
        tcp::endpoint endpoint(tcp::v4(), port);
        P2PNode node(io_context, endpoint, 1);
        std::cout << "do u want to connect to some server? yes - 1 / no - any other";
        std::cin >> option;
        if (option == 1)
        {
            std::cout << "enter the port you will be connecting to: " << std::endl;
            std::cin >> port;
            tcp::endpoint remote_endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), port);
            node.do_connect(remote_endpoint);
        }
        io_context.run();
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << "Exception was thrown in function: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cout << "Unknown exception in main !" << std::endl;
    }
```

P2PNode.h

```
#pragma once
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Protocol.h"


#define CONNECTING_NODE 1
#define CLIENT_NODE 2


using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using namespace std;
class ProtocolMessage;

class P2PNode
{
public:
    P2PNode(boost::asio::io_context& io_context, const tcp::endpoint& endpoint, int nodeType);
    void do_connect(const tcp::endpoint& endpoint);
private:
    void do_accept();
    void do_read(tcp::socket& socket);
    void do_write(tcp::socket& socket, std::size_t length);
    tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
    std::string data_;
    std::vector<tcp::socket> sockets_;
    tcp::socket listeningSocket_;
    int nodeType_;
    ProtocolMessage GenerateResponse(ProtocolMessage message);
    std::string combineSocketsToString();
};
```

P2PNode.cpp

```
P2PNode::P2PNode(boost::asio::io_context& io_context, const tcp::endpoint& endpoint, int nodeType)
    : acceptor_(io_context, endpoint), listeningSocket_(io_context) {
    this->nodeType_ = nodeType;
    do_accept();
}

void P2PNode::do_connect(const tcp::endpoint& endpoint)
{
    tcp::socket socket = tcp::socket(acceptor_.get_executor());
    std::cout << "executor: " << socket.get_executor() << std::endl;
    socket.async_connect(endpoint,
        [this, &socket, endpoint](boost::system::error_code ec)
        {
            std::cout << "------------do connect------------";
            if (!ec)
            {
                std::cout << "Connected to " << endpoint << std::endl;

                // Add the connected socket to the list of sockets
                sockets_.emplace_back(std::move(socket));

                // Send a message to the connected server
                std::string message = "Hello from node " + std::to_string(nodeType_);
                data_ = message;
                do_write(sockets_.back(), message.size());
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "Failed to connect to " << endpoint << ": " << ec.message() << std::endl;
            }
        });
}

void P2PNode::do_accept() {
    std::cout << "Start Listening" << std::endl;
    acceptor_.async_accept(
        [this](boost::system::error_code ec, tcp::socket socket) {
            if (!ec) {
                std::cout << "Connection established with " << socket.remote_endpoint() << std::endl;
                sockets_.emplace_back(std::move(socket));
                do_read(sockets_.back());
            }
            do_accept();
        });
}
```

I tried to get the executor from the 'listeningSocket_' but it doesnt worked.

Comment: "I want the listening port to connect to him" - that really doesn't mean anything to me. Can you be specific, and include the relevant code? `do_connect` is never called, e.g.. Here's a start for you http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ba5b396cce053165 (note that it's kinda crucial that `sockets_` is a list - or any other stable container, e.g. Do include things like that!)

Comment: sorry my bad. I want the listening port (for the previous example - 20) to connect to the new port I give him (in the previous example - 10).
and the main function when the do_connect called I will also add.

Comment: What does it mean for a (listening, or otherwise) port to connect to another port?

Comment: The listening port is the main port of the node where it gets others to connect to him, this is the port of the acceptor.
ButI want this port to also connect itself to other node, so it will start the conversation and the other node will accept it with the acceptor. 
sorry if the answer isn't clear I don't really understand the question.

Comment: Processes make connections, ports do not. If you mean that you "just" want to bind the local port on an outgoing connection, that's clearer. I will look at the code presented when I get back home

Comment: yes my bad if  I don't explained properly. I want to bind the port that I use for listening and accepting, to also connecting to other servers.
The point is if I am even able to do that? or if the listening port must be binded only for listening, rather than for listening and connecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`do_connect` has a problem:

```
void P2PNode::do_connect(tcp::endpoint endpoint) {
    std::cout << "------------do connect------------";
    tcp::socket socket = tcp::socket(acceptor_.get_executor());
    std::cout << "executor: " << socket.get_executor() << std::endl;

    socket.async_connect(endpoint, [this, &socket, endpoint](error_code ec) {
        if (!ec) {
            std::cout << "Connected to server " << socket.remote_endpoint() << std::endl;

            sockets_.push_back(std::move(socket));

            data_ = "Hello from node " + std::to_string(nodeType_);
            do_write(sockets_.back(), data_.size());
        } else {
            std::cout << "Failed to connect to " << endpoint << ": " << ec.message() << std::endl;
        }
    });
}
```

The local variable `socket` leaves scope before the async operation (`async_connect`) will ever start, which causes the operation to be canceled. Moving from the stale reference into the vector is [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You don't give the implementations of `do_read` or `do_write`, but in fact the use of `vector` all but guarantees that there will be more [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in the future because if you ever push another connection the vector may reallocate, which is UB when there are operations in flight on them. I suggest a container with suitable reference stability guarantees. `std::list` or `std::deque` would be of interest.

Assuming a choice for `std::list` this would be better:

```
void P2PNode::do_connect(tcp::endpoint endpoint) {
    std::cout << "------------do connect------------";

    auto& conn = sockets_.emplace_back(acceptor_.get_executor());
    std::cout << "executor: " << conn.get_executor() << std::endl;

    conn.async_connect(endpoint, [=, &conn](error_code ec) {
        if (!ec) {
            std::cout << "Connected to server " << conn.remote_endpoint() << std::endl;

            data_ = "Hello from node " + std::to_string(nodeType_);
            do_write(conn, data_.size());
        } else {
            std::cout << "Failed to connect to " << endpoint << ": " << ec.message() << std::endl;
        }
    });
}
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/53e23d79accf9997)**

```
// #pragma once
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
// #include "Protocol.h"

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
class ProtocolMessage;

class P2PNode {
    using error_code = boost::system::error_code;

  public:
    enum Type { CONNECTING_NODE = 1, CLIENT_NODE = 2 };
    P2PNode(boost::asio::io_context& io_context, tcp::endpoint endpoint, Type nodeType);
    void do_connect(tcp::endpoint endpoint);

  private:
    void do_accept();
    void do_read(tcp::socket& ) {}
    void do_write(tcp::socket&, size_t) {}

    tcp::acceptor          acceptor_;
    std::list<tcp::socket> sockets_;
    tcp::socket            listeningSocket_;
    std::string            data_;
    Type                   nodeType_;

    ProtocolMessage GenerateResponse(ProtocolMessage const& message);
    std::string     combineSocketsToString();
};

P2PNode::P2PNode(boost::asio::io_context& io_context, tcp::endpoint endpoint, Type nodeType)
    : acceptor_(io_context, endpoint)
    , listeningSocket_(io_context)
    , nodeType_(nodeType) {
    do_accept();
}

void P2PNode::do_connect(tcp::endpoint endpoint) {
    std::cout << "------------do connect------------";

    auto& conn = sockets_.emplace_back(acceptor_.get_executor());
    std::cout << "executor: " << conn.get_executor() << std::endl;

    conn.async_connect(endpoint, [=, this, &conn](error_code ec) {
        if (!ec) {
            std::cout << "Connected to server " << conn.remote_endpoint() << std::endl;

            data_ = "Hello from node " + std::to_string(nodeType_);
            do_write(conn, data_.size());
        } else {
            std::cout << "Failed to connect to " << endpoint << ": " << ec.message() << std::endl;
        }
    });
}

void P2PNode::do_accept() {
    std::cout << "Start Listening" << std::endl;

    acceptor_.async_accept([this](error_code ec, tcp::socket socket) {
        if (!ec) {
            std::cout << "Connection accepted from " << socket.remote_endpoint() << std::endl;
            sockets_.push_back(std::move(socket));
            do_read(sockets_.back());
        }
        do_accept();
    });
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) try {
    uint16_t const port = argc > 1 ? atoi(argv[1]) : 8989;

    std::cout << "listening port: " << port << std::endl;
    boost::asio::io_context io_context;
    P2PNode node(io_context, {tcp::v4(), port}, P2PNode::CONNECTING_NODE);

    if (uint16_t option, port; //
        std::cout << "Do you want to connect? yes - 1 / no - any other" && std::cin >> option &&
        option == 1) {
        std::cout << "port to connect: " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> port;
        node.do_connect({{},port});
    }
    io_context.run();
} catch (std::exception const& e) {
    std::cout << "Exception was thrown in function: " << e.what() << std::endl;
} catch (...) {
    std::cout << "Unhandled exception" << std::endl;
}
```

Testing with two instances:

```
g++ -std=c++20 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp 
(./a.out 7878 <<< "other")& sleep 1
(./a.out 8989 <<< "1 7878")&
```

Prints output like:

[image]

### Binding The Local Port

This will not lead to observable difference, unless you inspect the connections using `netstat` or `tcpview` et al.

I thought to just add the bind call:

```
auto& conn = sockets_.emplace_back(acceptor_.get_executor());
conn.open(acceptor_.local_endpoint().protocol());
conn.bind(acceptor_.local_endpoint());
```

However this leads to

```
Exception was thrown in function: bind: Address already in use [system:98 at /home/sehe/custom/superboost/boost/asio/detail/reactive_socket_service.hpp:161:5 in function 'boost::system::error_code boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_service<Protocol>::bind(boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_service<Protocol>::implementation_type&, const endpoint_type&, boost::system::error_code&)']
```

Setting the relevant options [doesn't fix it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f5cad85a1f9b0ee):

```
void P2PNode::do_accept() {
    std::cout << "Start Listening" << std::endl;

    acceptor_.set_option(tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
    acceptor_.async_accept([this](error_code ec, tcp::socket socket) {
         // etc.
```

I'd tend to conclude that it is not (portably) supported to bind to the address that the listener is using.

Comment: thanks that was very helpful and informative! although I get the error:
"cannot deduce 'auto' type" in the do_connect function on line: 
`auto& conn = sockets_.emplace_back(acceptor_.get_executor());`
Is there a way to not use the full type of the iterator?

Comment: tried using `typeId(sockets_.emplace_back(acceptor_.get_executor())).name()` get the type and just replace auto& with it. But the type I got was void and when replacing auto& with void there were also problems.

Comment: @Mart1n your compile/standard library vendor might simply [not be up-to-date with c++17](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/emplace_back) -

Comment: For your convenience: [c++17](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e516ac7dced909b9), [c++14](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3d76899a587adf67), [c++11](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d05ebe4b768789f), [c++03](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/15f90968045d48ae)